# How to parametrize options of a menu on Android?

Tags: android, android-menu

I want to show/hide some options of a menu on an Android application depending of some strings that I will set to true/false on `strings.xml` file.

As an example, I will have these strings on `strings.xml` file:

```
<string name="option1">false</string>
<string name="option2">true</string>
<string name="option3">true</string>
```

So in this case only `option2` and `option3` have to be shown.

On the other side, I mean, in code, I tried the following:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    if((getResources().getString(R.string.option1)).equals("false")){
        menu.getItem(R.id.option1).setVisible(false);
    }

    return true;
}
```

But `option1` is still being shown on the menu.

What should I do to parametrize these options? I could just remove these options but I would like that in the future if my clients want these options active again, I could do it easily changing false value to true.

**EDIT:** Here is my menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/option1"
            android:title="Option 1" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/option2"
            android:title="Option 2" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/option3"
            android:title="Option 3" />
        ....
    </group>
</menu>
```

---

**LAST UPDATE**

I have notice that I was getting `NullPointerException` because the name of the menu was wrong. I have fixed it and now it does not give me any error.

But my problem comes because I have two different layouts that contains two different menus (one in each layout) and I inflate each layout depending of one string that comes on the login.

For example, considering that the string to inflate the first layout is "hello" I display the layouts as follows on `onCreate` function of my `MainActivity`:

```
if("hello".equals(stringForLayout)){
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}else{
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_secondary);
}
```

How can I parametrize the options of both menus so if the first one is being shown and I want to hide one option, I would be able to refer to that option of that menu?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As @user3728999 said, you'd better go for a standard SharedPreferences solution. Then set your menu items visibility accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I found where my problems were.

The problem came because I did not notice that `onCreateOptionsMenu` and `onPrepareOptionsMenu` were not used so I deleted them.

Further, as I was using my menu inside a `NavigationView` I had to use, after inflate the `NavigationView` on my `onCreate` function of my `MainActivity` class, the following statement:

```
navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.option1).setVisible(false);
```

There, I did not have any problem to hide my menu item succesfully.

Answer (score 4):

If you use Strings (e.g. s1 & s2), you have to compare them like this:

if(s1.equals(s2)) {...}

Btw.: You can also look at Shared Preferences in the android documentation to get a cleaner solution. There you can define boolean variables for the different menu options.

Comment: OMG! I cannot believe I did that mistake. Some time without programming in Java and I returned to beginner mistakes :(. But I have another doubt, when I try to make the menuOption visible to false I get the following error: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.view.MenuItem android.view`. I tried with both `getItem` and `findItem` but with both of them I get the same error. Should I do the comparison in another place?

Comment: can you also post the xml with the menu?

Comment: I have added the xml of the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want to hide a specific menu item for a specific activity.

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuItem mSearch = menu.findItem(R.id.mSearch);
        mSearch.setVisible(false);
        invalidateOptionsMenu(); 
}
```